# ajax send() does not update address bar

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am on my first steps with ajax. Could somebody please help me understand why the ajax send() does not update the address bar? The connection works but it always prints "There is no variable!" PS: Please keep in mind that I DO NOT want to use JQuery.

> test.htm

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="posts"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var addressVariables = "sendvariable=test";
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "phpAjax.php";
    hr.open("GET", url, true);
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    hr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
            var returnData = hr.responseText;
            document.getElementById("centreSection").innerHTML = returnData;
        }
    };
    hr.send(addressVariables);
</script>

<section id="centreSection"></section>
</body>

</html>
```

> phpAjax.php

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['sendvariable'])){
    $testVar = $_GET['sendvariable'];
    echo "Ajax rocks !";
    echo $testVar;
} else {
    echo "There is no variable!";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the article about ajax at: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_http_send.asp it will help you to learn about how to send a request to a server
Now you can try the code following below(test.htm):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="posts"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var addressVariables = "sendvariable=test";
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "phpAjax.php"+'?'+addressVariables;
    hr.open("GET", url, true);
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    hr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
            var returnData = hr.responseText;
            document.getElementById("centreSection").innerHTML = returnData;
        }
    };
    hr.send();
</script>

<section id="centreSection"></section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is quite simple, with GET requests the send() function has no parameters. The parameters are only applicable for POST requests.

In order to pass GET variables to the PHP script, you'll have to append them to the URL much like you would in the browser as per css.cutter's example.

The spec for XMLHttpRequest's can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send and that explains the lot!

Answer (score 0):

Problem with your code is that you are using **POST** instead of **GET** method.

In **GET** method you send data in the url itself. And what you are doing is sending it as a **POST** method style.

Your script should be like below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var addressVariables = "sendvariable=test";

  var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  var url = "phpAjax.php?"+addressVariables;

  hr.open("GET", url, true);

  hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

  hr.onreadystatechange = function () {

     if (hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {

          var returnData = hr.responseText;

          document.getElementById("centreSection").innerHTML = returnData;
     }
  };

  hr.send();

</script>
```